# Saved draft of already-asked question staying in the 'ask a question' page

Tags: bug, asking-questions, draft

I had asked a question today around 8 PM ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51064246/1610034)). After 4 hours, when I click on `ask question` from the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) home page, I see my already-posted question still in the title and body input. See the image below. Notice the url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

[image]